# Getting error while trying to execute jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, windows, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm getting an error while trying to execute `jupyter-notebook` in the console, the error happen here:

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'
```

The strange thing is that it began to happen from one day to another, since until recently I could use jupyter-notebook perfectly, due to this error I uninstalled and then reinstalled anaconda, but the error persists.

My OS is Windows 10 and I installed the [64-bit installer with python 3.6](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows)

The Traceback is:

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Scripts>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1093, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 167, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 259, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 807, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 62, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import io
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 90, in <module>
    devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nul'
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: see: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9023

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but you should never *really* need to write to devnull. Just write to somewhere else, and delete it later if you don't need it. It's kind of a pain, but should work for the time being.

Comment: Well, for now I just deleted this [chunk of code](https://i.imgur.com/mtqmw4w.png) that was in `io.py` to be able to work, if someone find out the correct solution it would be awesome.